# Add tenants connectionstring and subdomain as a claim to the owin identity

Tags: asp.net, owin, multi-tenant

Is it secure to add the tenants subdomain and database connectionstring as a claim to the user `ClaimsIdentity` during login?

In this way we won't need to access the master tenants database and we will only work with this `ClaimsIdentity`.

Or can we create a custom `ClaimsIdentity` which contains a `Tenant` object that contains connection string and subdomain?

Comment: You shouldn't store ephemeral state inside Claims, such as connection-string information. You can use server-side state for that, which can be populated during `Session_Start` - you could also use an in-process in-memory cache which would allow you to have machine-specific state too.

Comment: @Dai, MemoryCache was the second option for this. So we will look into that.